# Sequence numbers for lists with lists

Tags: python

I am preparing a list of lists. the initial list can contain any number of entries but the sub-lists each contain 3 entries, eg:

```
colony =  [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c'], [3, 'b', 'c'], [4, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c']]
```

The first entry in each of the sub-lists is the sequence number of the entry and needs to be sequential,

> ie. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...

A, B and C are the column headings, the data is in the subsequent lists. My difficulty is that if the number of sub-lists that I need to add is say 5, then the sequence number of every entry is 5.How can I change my code to insert the correct sequence number in each sub-list:

```
colony = [['A', 'B', 'C']]
add_colony = [0, 0, 0]

R = 5
i = 1

for i in range(R):
    add_colony[0] = i + 1
    add_colony[1] = 'b'
    add_colony[2] = 'c'
    colony.append(add_colony)
    i = i + 1

print()
print('colony = ', colony)
```

produces:

```
colony =  [['A', 'B', 'C'], [5, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c']]
```

not:

```
colony =  [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c'], [3, 'b', 'c'], [4, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c']]
```

I have tried all sorts of variations but end up with the incorrect output.

Thanks in advance
Bob

Answer (score 4):

You are permanently mutating and appending the same `list` object `add_colony`. All the lists in `colony` are references to this same object. You have to create a new list for each loop iteration:

```
for i in range(R):
    add_colony = [0, 0, 0]  # without this line ...
    add_colony[0] = i + 1   # ... this mutation will affect all the references in colony
    add_colony[1] = 'b'
    add_colony[2] = 'c'
    colony.append(add_colony)
```

Or shorter:

```
for i in range(R):
    colony.append([i + 1, 'b', 'c'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there fellow University of Melbourne Student!

As @schwobaseggl mentioned, you need to create a new list object on each iteration of your loop, or you just keep appending the same object over and over again. You could also just make `add_colony` have the default values `['b', 'c']`, and `insert()` the new `i` value at the beginning each of the list.

Here is an example:

```
colony = [['A', 'B', 'C']]

R = 5

for i in range(R):
    add_colony = ['b', 'c']
    add_colony.insert(0, i+1)
    colony.append(add_colony)

print('colony = ', colony)
```

Which Outputs:

```
colony =  [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c'], [3, 'b', 'c'], [4, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c']]
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
colony = [['A', 'B', 'C']] + [[i + 1] + ['b', 'c'] for i in range(R)]
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you have all been a great help to me.

Comment: @Bob No worries, make sure you accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

1 liner list comp that mutates the original list without saving it to a variable (kinda weird):

```
[colony.append([i, 'b', 'c']) for i in range(1, R + 1)]
```

`print(colony)` outputs

> [['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'b', 'c'], [3, 'b', 'c'], [4, 'b', 'c'], [5, 'b', 'c']]